# Какой оптимальный способ конкантенировать 100 строк в Java в 2017 году?

Tags: java, строки, java-8

С давних пор есть мнение, что конкатенировать строки в Java нужно при помощи `StringBuilder`, но с появлением Java 8 появилось много статей о том, что можно складывать строки используя только `+` или при помощи `Joiner`-а.

Каков самый эффективный способ конкатенации большого количества строк в Java 8?

Comment: Я прям рекомендую посмотреть доклад Шипилева Катехизис java.lang.String https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZFe3m1DV1A

Comment: *днако, четкого ответа как склеить 100 строк в 2к17 я так и нашел.* - любым доступным способом